# Will Christians be judged?

Tags: judgment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Biblical basis for multiple judgments?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5604/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-multiple-judgments)

Romans 12:1 says "There is no condemnation for those in Christ Jesus" and 2 Cor 5 :17 says we are new creations and the old has passed away. I take it that this means our past life is cleaned out and we start afresh. So on the judgement day Christians will not be judged as the slate is new, right? How does this reconcile with Heb 9:27 which says ".. just as people are destined to die once, and after that to face judgment" . This Hebrews verse seems to say there is going to be judgment  no matter what. Please shed some light.

Comment: See http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/whats-the-difference-between-the-judgment-seat-of-christ-and-the-great-white-th?rq=1  your question is answered there.And here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5604/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-multiple-judgments/5612#5612

Comment: By the way you want Romans 8:1 not 12:1

Comment: This question may have a similar answer as the linked ones, but it is a different question.

Comment: New creation means your old spirit is dead, not your old fleshly life (body,soul).  You literally are a new creation in the spirit which is the real you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes everyone will be judged:

> 2 Corinthians 5:10 New King James Version (NKJV) - For we must ***ALL***
>   appear before the judgment seat of Christ, that each one may receive
>   the things done in the body, according to what he has done, whether
>   good or bad.

but not all will be condemned:

> Romans 8:1 New King James Version (NKJV) - There is therefore now no
>   condemnation to those who are in Christ Jesus,[a] who do not walk
>   according to the flesh, but according to the Spirit.